# Merging Two Outer Lists Based on Iterated Inner List Value

Tags: python, list, iteration

I have two lists of lists - i.e.

```
[['1', 'expired', 'test', '0'], ['31', 'active', 'test', '1']]
```

as well as

```
[['1', 'Andrew', 'Alexander'], ['31', 'John', 'Smith']]
```

Lets call them `list1` and `list2`

I want to merge `list1` and `list2`, but ONLY when (note, this is pseudocode, trying to figure out how to program this in Python)

```
x[0] in list1 == x[0] in list2
```

I'm not sure how to write this out.

By merge I mean (pseudocode)

```
list[x] = list1[x] + list2[x] while x[0] in list1 == x[0] in list2
```

Output desired:

```
[['1', 'expired', 'test', '0', '1', 'Andrew', 'Alexander'], ['31', 'active', 'test', '1', '31', 'John', 'Smith']]
```

The only critical point is that not all of the x[0]'s are going to match up perfectly.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by 'merge' here? What's the desired output?

Comment: Please give exactly what you want the output of your example to be -- it still isn't that clear to me.

Comment: Still trying to figure out which is the correct answer that works for me. A lot of my unselected answers are like that. And I have been trying to give check marks to questions in the past too. I'm trying to be a good member of the community!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using agf's idea of employing a [collections.defaultdict](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict), this in O(m+n) where `m` and `n` are the lengths of the lists.

```
import collections
import itertools

x=[['1', 'expired', 'test', '0'], ['31', 'active', 'test', '1']]
y=[['1', 'Andrew', 'Alexander'], ['31', 'John', 'Smith']]

result=collections.defaultdict(list)
for item in itertools.chain(x,y):
    result[item[0]].append(item)
result=[list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(value)) for value in result.values()]
print(result)
```

yields

```
[['1', 'expired', 'test', '0', '1', 'Andrew', 'Alexander'], ['31', 'active', 'test', '1', '31', 'John', 'Smith']]
```

---

In the comments the OP says the desired output is

```
[['1', 'expired', 'test', '0', 'Andrew', 'Alexander'], ['31', 'active', 'test', '1', 'John', 'Smith']]
```

(this is different than the desired output posted in the original question.)

Then:

```
import collections
import itertools

x=[['1', 'expired', 'test', '0'], ['31', 'active', 'test', '1']]
y=[['1', 'Andrew', 'Alexander'], ['31', 'John', 'Smith']]

result={}
for item in itertools.chain(x,y):
    result.setdefault(item[0],item[:1]).extend(item[1:])
result=result.values()
print(result)
```

This is one of the few times I've found using [setdefault](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault) more convenient than `collections.defaultdict`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want `[[1, 'a'], [2, 'b']]` and `[[1, 'c'], [3, 'd']]` merged to `[[1, 'a', 'c'], [2, 'b'], [3, 'd']]`:

```
from collections import defaultdict
dict1_2 = defaultdict(list)
dict1_2.update((item[0], item[1:]) for item in list1)
for item in list2:
    dict1_2[item[0]].append(item[1:])
```

if you want them merged to `[[1, 'a', 'c']]`:

```
dict1 = dict((item[0], item[1:]) for item in list1)
dict1_2 = {}
for item in list2:
    key = item[0]
    if key in dict1:
        dict1_2[key] = dict1[key] + item[1:]
```

You're using the `item[0]` as keys, so you should use a datatype that fits that. In this case, that's a dictionary / mapping.

This works (on average) in linear time, O(m+n) (where m and n are the lengths of the lists). Any solution using nested loops or similar will be O(m*n)

If you really need the data back as a list, you can do

```
list1_2 = [[key] + value for key, value in dict1_2.iteritems()]
```

Comment: They aren't all the same. There are some that are different/non-existent in the other list. That's why I am doing this in Python, rather than say, just merging the two lists together in Excel.

Comment: That being said, I want  [['1', 'expired', 'test', '0', 'Andrew', 'Alexander'], 
 ['31', 'active', 'test', '1', 'John', 'Smith']]

Comment: @Andrew Re-re edited. Depending on what you want done with items in only one list or the other, I provided two versions.

Answer (score 0):

```
resultlist = []
for x in list1:
    for y in list2:
        if x[0] == y[0]:
            resultlist.append(x+y)
```

Comment: OP said items should be added only when the first element is the same in both lists - or have I got it wrong?

Comment: This is O(len(list1)*len(list2)) time, it can be done in linear average time.

Answer (score 0):

Not the best way, but definitely concise and hard to read, if that's what you're after:

```
>>> l1 = [['1', 'expired', 'test', '0'], ['31', 'active', 'test', '1']]
>>> l2 = [['1', 'Andrew', 'Alexander'], ['31', 'John', 'Smith']]

>>> [sl1 + list(*[sl2[1:] for sl2 in l2 if sl2[0]==sl1[0]]) for sl1 in l1]

[['1', 'expired', 'test', '0', 'Andrew', 'Alexander'], ['31', 'active', 'test', '1', 'John', 'Smith']]
```

Please don't actually use this in any real code.

Comment: You want `next((sl2[1:] for sl2 in l2 if sl2[0]==sl1[0]), [])` rather than that crazy list thing you came up with :). Also, this will add items that only exist in `list1` but not items that only exist in `list2` -- I don't know if he wants them added or not, but I'm sure he doesn't want it asymmetrical.

Answer (score 0):

```
l1 = [['1', 'expired', 'test', '0'], ['31', 'active', 'test', '1']]
l2 = [['1', 'Andrew', 'Alexander'], ['31', 'John', 'Smith'], ['51', 'Johnny', 'Nomatch']]

from itertools import groupby, chain
from operator import itemgetter

all = sorted(chain(l1,l2), key=itemgetter(0)) # puts the related lists together
groups = groupby(all, itemgetter(0)) # groups them by first element
chains = (group for key, group in groups) # get each group
print [list(chain.from_iterable(g)) for g in chains] # merge them
```

It's a oneliner ;-)

Items that don't match are included. You can filter them out by simply checking `len(group) > 4`.